# Angular & IE version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am new to angular. We are going to start a project with IE as browser. Please can i know that which version of IE is well compatible with angular js. It would be great to know angular version as well.

Comment: Refer this link for ans. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) for official IE Compatibility from Angular.

According to [this](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/docs/guide/ie), angular dropped IE 8 support in angular 1.3

> Note: AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.